# __init__.py seemingly not working

Tags: python, package

New to Python.  I'm on Windows and Python2.7.

I have confirmed that my directory is setup in PYTHONPATH by looking in sys.path from IDLE.

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

This shows me that c:\users\owner\documents\PythonProjects is definitely in the path.  Furthermore in that directory I have a .py file which can be imported into IDLE.

The trouble is c:\user\owner\documents\PythonProjects\testPackage\test.py is not loading.  The error is ImportError:No module named testPackage.test.

I have tried an empty `__init__.py` as well as an `__init__.py` with some trivial code inside.  The `__init__.py` is in the PythonProjects folder as it should be.  Why am I getting this error?

Comment: pythongprojects? thong? typo, but a funny one :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it should be in `testPackage\`.

Comment: To clarify, `__init__.py` should be in the `testPackage` folder, not the `PythonProjects` folder.

Answer (score 0):

There must be an `__init__.py` file in every directory, so if your structure is:

```
projects/
   TestProject/
       __init__.py
       test.py
```

And the path to `projects` is on your PYTHONPATH, then you should be able to import the `test` module.

Comment: There is no need to have `__init__.py` in any path in `sys.path`.